# Writing int type to a file and reading back string types from the same file (C++ i/o fstream)

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm currently learning writing to and reading from a file in C++, and I stumbled across something I'm not sure I understand.

I'm writing 5 different integers to "ages.txt" file and then I'm using a `read_file()` function to read the content of that file and output it to a console. What I don't really understand is that when writing to a file I'm using `int` type, and reading back from it I'm using `string` type, and numbers are still being read correctly from the "ages.txt" file.

Does that mean there is some conversion happening in the backgroud?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void read_file()
{
    ifstream file ("ages.txt");

    vector<string> read_age;

    string input;
    while(file >> input)
    {
        read_age.push_back(input);
    }

    for(string age : read_age)
    {
    cout << age << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ofstream file ("ages.txt");

    if(file.is_open())
    {
    cout << "File was opened" << endl;
    }

    vector<int> ages;
    ages.push_back(12);
    ages.push_back(13);
    ages.push_back(14);
    ages.push_back(15);
    ages.push_back(16);

    for(int age : ages)
    {
        file << age << endl;
    }

    read_file();

    return 0;
}
```

I tried changing string to char type everywhere in the `read_file()` function and then output of my console was as follows (with the data that's already in "ages.txt" file):

```
File was opened
1
2
1
3
1
4
1
5
1
6
```

Comment: I suggest that you look at the file content. It will help you to find an answer.

Comment: gcc seems to do what you want: https://godbolt.org/z/M5Wqh1EaM. But still, you probably want to read to `int`s instead of `string`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does mean some conversion is happening.

Using `<<` converts whatever you are writing to text. Text is *typeless*, a sequence of digits could be an integer or it could be a string. Similarly `>>` converts whatever text you are reading to some type. Now there is a potential problem here in that some text cannot be converted to some types, but anything can be read as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify read_file function to read integers instead of strings:

```
void read_file() 
{
    ifstream file("ages.txt");

    vector<int> read_age;

    int input;
    while (file >> input)
    {
        read_age.push_back(input);
    }

    for (int age : read_age)
    {
        cout << age << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, I'm aware of that, but I did it on purpose here because that was my initial question - I can store `int` in my "ages.txt" file, but when trying to read from it, I can use type `string`, and won't get an error.